# Customer Search By Email

Tags: acumatica

We have created a new OzLINK_WSE Web Service Endpoint for 5.30.001 and created a definition OzCustomer to enable searching based on Email address.

[WSE Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZSmJ.png)

We have tried two different searches but neither of them are working:-

The first (GetList)

```
var cust = c.GetList(new OzCustomer { Email = new StringValue { Value = "info@active-staffing.con" } }, false).Cast<OzCustomer>();
```

returns this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> 
PX.Api.ContractBased.OperationDoesNotSupportValuesException: Operation does not support values.
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(EntityGateBase gate, String version, String name, 
   EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGate.GetList(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The second (Get)

```
var cust = c.Get(new OzCustomer { Email = new StringValue { Value = "info@active-staffing.con" } });
```

returns a different error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Api.ContractBased.MoreThanOneEntitySatisfiesTheConditionException: More than one entity satisfies the condition.
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Get(EntityGateBase gate, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntity, PXGraph graph)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGate.Get(Entity entity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Could someone please advise how we can search for a Contact via Email address and avoid these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StringSearch` instead of `StringValue` in `GetList`:

```
var cust = c
  .GetList(
    new OzCustomer {
      Email = new StringSearch { Value = "info@active-staffing.con" }
    }, false)
  .Cast<OzCustomer>();
```